# ActiveX textbox displayes dates as number

Tags: excel

I have ActiveX textbox and linked cell that is I21. I21 is set to be a date but in ActiveX textbox I see number. What is wrong here?

[image]

Here are the properties:

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong. Use `Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")` to set the text box value.

Comment: You mean to input to formula bar instead of `=EMBED("Forms.TextBox.1";"")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way to copy the format from the linked cell to the control, nor to directly set a format for the control. Therefore the only way I could figure is to use the Worksheet Change event to fill the TextBox control with the value on the worksheet. Unfortunately, this is a one-way street.

Paste the code below to the code module of the worksheet on which you have your textbox. Leave the ActiveX control's `LinkedCell` property blank.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim LinkedCell As Range

    Set LinkedCell = Range("I21")
    With Target
        If .Address = LinkedCell.Address Then
            Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(LinkedCell.Value, "dd mmm yyyy")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How it should be if my I21 is actually on Sheet1 and TextBox1 on Sheet2?

Comment: The code would have to be on the code sheet of the worksheet on which the cell is. `Me.TextBox1.Value` would have to be replaced with `Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox1.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Variatus suggestion works fine. However I have tried myself another approach and decided to use this one. Originally posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul)

Insert this to standard module:

```
Public Function FMT$(ByVal Value, ByVal strFormat)
    FMT = VBA.Format$(Value, strFormat)
End Function
```

Then convert date by using this formula for example in cell I22: `=FMT(I21;"dd.mm.yyyy")`

Finally link ActiveX textbox to I22. Your date should be displayed in the correct way.